# Is there a way for a function to return either ints or strings, depending on the input?

Tags: function, types, f#, return-type

I got this homework assignment (Couldn't add the homework tag). This is just a training problem, not part of a hand-in.
I made a recursive function "eval" that evaluates common operations on integers (+, -, *, /)
So far, the function can evaluate addition, multiplication and subtraction.

```
type expr =
    | Const of int
    | Add of expr * expr
    | Mul of expr * expr
    | Sub of expr * expr

let rec eval (n: expr): int =
    match n with
        | Const n -> n
        | Add (a, b) -> eval a + eval b
        | Mul (a, b) -> eval a * eval b
        | Sub (a, b) -> eval a - eval b
```

This function works perfectly. Next I have to extend the expr type, to allow for division, by adding:

```
| Div of expr * expr
```

Also I need to deal with the case of zero division, by making a new type:

```
('a, 'b) result
```

Which is the new return type of eval (This is in the assignment description, so i have to do that).
This is my attempt:

```
type ('a, 'b) result =
    | Ok of int
    | Err of string

let rec eval (n: expr): ('a, 'b)result =
    match n with
        | Const n -> Ok(Const n)
        | Add (a, b) -> Ok(eval a + eval b)
        | Mul (a, b) -> OK(eval a * eval b)
        | Sub (a, b) -> Ok(eval a - eval b)
        | Div (_, Const 0) -> Err "zero division"
        | Div (a, b) -> Ok(eval a / eval b)
```

But I get an error saying that the operators +, -, * and / isn't defined for type ('a, 'b) result, which makes sense. So my question is, is there a way for a new type to inherit from other types? I can't type something like:

```
type ('a, 'b) result =
    | int
    | Err of string
```

Why is that not a thing? Do I have to specify some keyword so be associated with int, if I use int in a new type? f# wants the same output type, no matter the input, is there a way around this? Could I tell the function that the output is either an integer or a string, if I didn't create the new type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.
Like you said F# only allows one return type.

In this case your `result` type has 2 possible set of values, the `Ok` values and the `Error` values.
Your code needs to consider both posibilites, you cannot ignore one.
Remember `eval a` does not return an `int` anymore, now it returns a `result`, which may or may not have an `int` inside it.

After you `eval a` and `eval b` but before you call `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`, you need to check if either result is an `Error`. Only if both are `Ok` can you then apply the operator. If any of them is an `Error` you have to return the error, right?

You can use `match` to check (and to extract the `int`), for instance:

```
match eval  a , eval  b  with
|     Ok    a', Ok    b' -> Ok(a' + b')
|     Error e , _    
|     _       , Error e  -> Error e
```

Remember you do not need to copy the instruction above 4 times.
You can create a function and pass the operator as a parameter
using this syntax: `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, `(/)`.

Another tip: you are considering only the case of division by `Const 0`.
What happens if you are dividing by a calculated `0`, for instance `5/(1 - 1)`?

In Functional Programming there is another way of dealing with this.
What you need in the end is a `Bind` function (or `Apply`).
A good resource to learn about it is this site: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: This solves my problem. However I have a question. In your pattern matching, you have a pattern that you don't finish with ->. Does that mean that the match will return the same as the next pattern?

Comment: Correct. It is like an `or` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if F# allows you to do something like:

`type Result = int | string`

It's not an unreasonable expectation, TypeScript allows exactly this. F# doesn't, it has you define a new type for each case.

`type Result = Ok of int | Err of string`

This makes it a bit annoying in this case, granted, but it does make it more natural to create Discriminated Unions - unions "discriminated" in some way, here by their type name. In TypeScript, you would need to add a common property to each case, which is a bit clumsy.

The fundamental difference is that F# builds on the .NET type system which is nominal, and TypeScript is a structural type system. .NET distinguishes types by their names, TypeScript distinguishes types by their contents. So you'll find yourself creating a bit more type names in F#.